# Unique name of android phone

Tags: android, deviceid

I want to get a unique name or id of the android phone by using the following :

```
String uniqueID = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
    android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

but it is return null , i do not know what is the problem .
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't use `ANDROID_ID`.  It's been known to be null sometimes and it can change after a factory reset.  The device id on the other hand is always non-null (in my experience at least), and unique.

You can add this code to your `Activity` to retrieve the unique device id of the phone:

```
TelephonyManager tm =
  (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String device = tm.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: That will also require the READ_PHONE_STATE permission. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work on a phone without a radio, like a WiFi-only tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with context,

```
String m_androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```